# How relevant was manual bit-shifting for multiplication and division in early C and C++ compilers?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Today it's often best to trust the compiler. But back in the day of simple processors and writing code in assembly, a programmer knew that bit-shifting was not only faster but also saved precious memory when compiled to binary.

When C and C++ compilers were still very young, did assembly programmers follow tradition by bit-shifting like they did in assembly or could they also trust the compiler to optimize this away? Was there a predisposition to continue to bit-shift due to compilers being used that were non-optimizing?

There appears to be a conflict with opinions on bit-shifting today. There is the educational side which expresses why it's faster than multiplication. But this does not always translate to the most optimal code. And yet it is common to find explicit shifting in algorithms and expressions for both old and new code alike.

For some added perspective, I'm interested in learning from history. In 70s and 80s, how did *experienced* programmers consider whether to bit-shift or multiply/divide? Was there a certain technology that made this effort largely obsolete such as speculative execution or branch prediction?

What I find the most difficult to understand is that I will most often encounter code where the shift is done against a very small constant like 1 or 2. I would expect these kinds of shifts to be the easiest for the compiler to recognize. Why then would someone choose to still use such shifts?

I may have made some false assumptions. I welcome any comments on this subject as well.

Comment: I assume it was more of : compile, check compiler generated asm, write hand-written asm for places you could optimize yourself better than the compiler.

Comment: In the "good-old-days" (8086) if a CPU instruction said it took 5 clock cycles, then that is how long it took. No speculative execution, no parallel operands etc.  You could just add up the time taken.  Today that is not possible.  You built patterns of code you tested and re-used.

Comment: As an experienced programmer of the 70s and 80s, the compiler even then did a good job.  Sure, one would hack in `<< 2` for a `* 4` every now and then, but it was still only linear improvement.  Really good optimization then and now still benefit with higher level optimizations rather than small stuff.

Comment: Once I got an optimizing C compiler (which was about $2000 back in the day), I stopped programming in assembly.  In C or C++, if you type `x = y * 4;` the optimizer is smart enough to turn that into a left-shift by two... if that is, indeed, faster.

Comment: This stuff is considered micro-optimizations and you might get more performance differences if you move your compiler binary to a different working directory before launching (["Performance Matters" by Emery Berger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-TLSBdHe1A))

Comment: In the days of old, multiplication versus bit shifting was largely dependent on the microprocessor.  Some processors didn't have a multiply instruction, so a multiply function was called (usually this is where the bit shift and add was performed).  There were some multiply functions that were more efficient than the processor's multiplication instruction.  The choice of multiplication function versus instruction was primarily due to the processor's capability.

Comment: Back in those early days, compilers were specifically written for a special processor.  Code sharing was not an issue.  As the processor innovations became more frequent, compiler development time needed to match.  Thus they split up the compiler into things like the "front-end" and the "back-end".  To match a compiler to a processor, only the "back-end" needed changing.  The difference between a compiler for an 8057 and an 8086 would be the "back-end".  The "back-end" is where the multiplication algorithm would be placed (or a simple multiplication instruction emitted).

Comment: Modern processors are fast enough now that bit shifting can be considered a *micro-optimization*.  The time spent developing micro-optimization would be better spent on robustness or features.  The performance gained by the micro-optimizations is negligible, except in the extreme cases.  For example, you may save 100 microseconds with a micro-optimization, only to have it wasted waiting for input from a user or device (like hard drive).  For me, it's still a hard habit to let go of (I'm still optimizing when I code).

Comment: "shift is done against a very small constant like 1 or 2". What do you mean here? `1<<X` or `X<<1`?

Comment: In my opinion -- and this is only opinion -- the vast majority of the time, shifts as allegedly "fast" multiplies are done because someone's heard it's a good idea.  It's not done because it *is* a good idea, or because it makes that much of a difference, or because it's the most important out of a wider set of such microoptimizations.  It's done out of habit, and because it's an exceptionally easy trick to remember.  And besides people making this "optimization" out of habit, the same goes for people who go around (like here on SO) suggesting that other people do it in their posted code.

Comment: @SteveSummit: It was definitely a good idea long time ago. And it still can be a good idea in certain cases (if we know that the value is non-negative): https://godbolt.org/z/z4T8tK (sure, we could cast the number to unsigned, do the shift there, but it can be more confusing).

Comment: @geza And yet, a long time ago, I remember posting somewhere, in an earlier iteration of this age-old question, that Ritchie's original `cc` for the PDP-11 -- the one that had to run in 64k of RAM -- was capable of replacing shifts by multiplications where appropriate, and that was without even running its optimizer.

Comment: @geza `if we know that the value is non-negative` in that case the argument should be `unsigned int` and not `int`, and if you do so both `a/2` and `a>>1` result in the same machine code.

Comment: @SteveSummit: yeah, perhaps. It is one of the easiest optimizations. Maybe I'll check it out, as I remember that the source code is available for some version of his compiler

Comment: @t.niese: what if that `int` can be negative, but the division is in a branch, where we know that it is positive (and the compiler cannot figure it out?). Or there can be a lot of cases, where we know that a resulting `int` expression is positive, but the compiler cannot figure it out.

Comment: @geza I think that's what logical shifting is intended to address by ignoring the signed bit, compared to traditional arithmetic shifting.

Comment: @geza Even then you should make that clear in your code by doing something like:  `unsigned int c = a;  return c/2` or `return static_cast<unsigned int>(a)/2`. And then the compiler knows what to do. `where we know that it is positive` well you know it at the moment of writing, maybe another person working on the code knows it too. But what if someone needs to look t your code in a few months, and does not know it (anymore), then it looks like a possible error.

Comment: @t.niese: Sure. If it is not obvious by the variable names, then of course a comment helps.

Comment: @Zhro: I'm not sure what you mean. The difference between in my example is, that for negative numbers, division by power-of-2, and arithmetic shifting can give a different (off-by-one) result. So there need to be some additional logic to fix this.

Comment: @geza It would be obvious if you use the correct type. It does not make any sense to use a signed type if you expect the value to be always non-negative. Why to solve it with a comment if you can explicitly tell it using the correct type. That helps both the compiler and the reader.

Comment: @t.niese: I disagree on this one, but let's not discuss this here :) You can read a lot of material, discussion on this.

Comment: I started programming C in the early 80s, and mainly for embedded systems like 8051. After some typical noob's errors I got used to write multiplications/divisions if I mean multiplications/divisions, and shifts if I mean shifts. For example if you like to scan a bit pattern I'll write `for (m = 1; m != 0; m <<= 1) ...` because multiplication will be the wrong concept. However, when a compiled code needs to be optimized beyond faster algorithms, I used shifts for multiplication/division. But that happened just once a year or so, and always with a comment!

Comment: "_Why then would someone choose to still use such shifts?_" One valid reason would be because that's how the original _algorithm_ is defined. If you're evaluating a mathematical equation, use `x * 2`; if you're doing bit-twiddling (e.g. a linear-feedback shift registers, or [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register)), then use `x << 1`. Even if they're "doing the same thing", each more clearly represents the underlying algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to remember is that compilers themselves had to run under rather tight memory constraints.  Given a choice between having to use shifts when one wants efficient computation, or having the compiler include code to optimize that but then having less storage available to the compiler for everything else, the former option would have been seen as preferable much more often than today.